# Boundary of output raster for kernel density tool not congruent w shapefile boundary

Tags: kernel-density

I am using the [Kernel Density tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 to visualize population density around two metro area transit lines. According to ESRI: "The Kernel Density tool uses an algorithm to calculate density of point features around each neighborhood. The algorithm determines the default search radius (bandwidth), which allows for better weighting of highly dense points and smoother outputs. The following ArcGIS Help document, [How Kernel Density works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-kernel-density-works.htm), further describes the tool." - [source](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012211)

The metro areas are Portland, OR and Charlotte, NC.

The tool input is a census tract shapefile joined with a population data table.

The resulting raster has the same boundary as a tract shapefile for one metro but is just a rectangle for other.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Kernel Density Tool results:

- Portland, OR metro census tracts

[image: PortlandOR metro census tracts]

- Charlotte, NC metro census tracts

[image: CharlotteNC tracts]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Your screenshots don't appear to have been added correctly - can you please [edit] your question to include any missing info.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Desktop or something else?